# How do I delete text between two symbols and stay in edit mode?

Tags: vim

Right now this is what I do if I want to replace the text between 2 quotes:

```
"IWantToReplaceThisSOOOOOOOOBADDDDDDD"
```

I do `vi"s` because that yanks/deletes the text and puts me in the middle of the quotes *in edit mode*.

So often all I want is to delete that text and type something else in its place though. `di"` does almost what i want but it doesn't put me in edit mode. Is there a way I could do that but be placed in edit mode?

Comment: If you position the cursor on the `I`, you can do `ct"`.  It means "change until for first occurence of `"`".  See [motion.txt](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#motion.txt) and [c](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#c).  Or use `ci"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. What you call "edit mode" is actually called "insert mode".

   See `:help vim-modes`.
2. The `c` operator does exactly what you want:

   ```
   ci"
   ```

   See `:help c`, `:help operator`, `:help navigation`.